# jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: PamtiOdabranog.php?vlado=true

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal, easyphp

I have a weird problem.
When I am trying to call my PHP script from HTML I catch an exception from the title.
The script is called when I click on the picture. 
The source code is working fine if I right click/open in new window.
It's also working if I throw jQuery out of my project.

Here is my PHP script and a section of the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>A.E.Z. d.o.o. Poduzeće za zastupanje u osiguranju</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Prodaja svih vrsta osiguranja!">
  <meta name="keywards" content="osiguranje, sviben, aez, a.e.z., jeftino, štednja, automobil, kuća"><!--ubaciti kljucne rijeci-->
  <meta name="author" content="Sandro Sviben">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="stil.css">-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a data-toggle="pill" href="PamtiOdabranog.php?vlado=true" ><img src="Vlado.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive" name="vlado"></a> </div>
```

My PHP script:

```
<?php

        if(isset($_GET['sandro'])) //ako je kliknut na sliku ili rijec sandro
        {
            echo "vraća sandro<br>";
            $on_klik_on_picture_or_name = "Sandro";
        }
        elseif(isset($_GET['vlado']))
        {   
            echo "vraća vlado<br>";
            $on_klik_on_picture_or_name = "Vlado";
        }
        elseif(isset($_GET['ljerka']))
        {   
            echo "vraća ljerka<br>";
            $on_klik_on_picture_or_name = "Ljerka";
        }
        elseif(isset($_GET['marina']))
        {   
            echo "vraća marina<br>";
            $on_klik_on_picture_or_name = "Marina";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Niste odabrali zatpunika!";   
        }
        return $on_klik_on_picture_or_name;

?>
```

Comment: Your error is a javascript error, not a PHP error. Show your javascript.

Comment: I didnt write any javascript code, it is integrated with bootstrap